# How to copy a Word table to Wordpress wysiwyg editor

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, wysiwyg

I am having Word documents for the default page markup. I can copy everything I need, except tables.

Is it possible to have a table in a Word document and copy them straight into the Wordpres wysiwyg editor?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Create a Word document with some text and a Table with some information
- Copy it, and past it into the Wordpress editor
- You see directly that the table formatting is *deleted* and the text from the tables is shown instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the TinyMCE Advanced plugin which adds a Paste from Word button.  In my experience, copying and pasting directly from Word will make some pretty messy code on the page.  It would be better to copy the text you need into the Wordpress Editor and rebuild the look of it. TinyMCE Advanced (and probably other plugins) will also have some buttons to help you set up tables if you really need to do that.

Comment: The problem is that the "Paste from Word" also strips every table. I also have the Advanced plugin, and it add the table functionality, but I cannot copy them from Word into TinyMCE.

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize TinyMCE did that.  I guess I don't use tables much.  In this thread at Wordpress.org http://wordpress.org/support/topic/working-with-tables-in-wordpress  someone suggests using the FCKEditor plugin.  Maybe that will work.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately if I try the demo of FCKEditor, it also wont work.

Comment: Try the "Word to html plugin".

Answer (score 3):

Another easy solution is using the following online tool:

http://tableizer.journalistopia.com/

This tool converts Word, Excel tables into HTML text.

This was my table in Word:

[image]

This is the output of Tableizer:

[image]